# Know if value is defined as Nullable or NotNullable when resolving custom scalar type

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, transit, sanctuary

I'm creating custom scalar types that override the built in `Int` and `Float`.  I'd like to know whether the schema defines the value as nullable or not.  I'd like to resolve an `Int` differently than `Int!` in my custom scalar type

What I want to do is within the resolver of the custom scalar type know whether the value is defined as Nullable or not in the schema so that I can resolve them differently and throw a custom error.

```
const resolvers = {
  // ...
  Int: new GraphQL.GraphQLScalarType ({
    name: 'Int',
    description: 'Custom Int type',
    serialize (val, isNullable) {

    },
    parseValue (val, isNullable) {
      // assume this parses the value
      const value = transit.read (val);

      // this does some type checking (using a library called sanctuary)
      if (S.is ($.Integer) (value)) {
        // if Nullable we want to return a maybe type
        if (isNullable) return S.Just (value);
        return value;
      }
      return isNullable ? S.Nothing : new Error ();
    },
    parseLiteral (ast) {

    },
  }),
}
```

The result for an `Int` (Nullable) would be of type `Maybe Integer` and the result of the `Int!` (Non-Nullable) would be of type `Integer`

Comment: Are you trying to differentiate `42 :: Integer` from `42 :: Nullable Integer`? In other words, do you want to infer type from value?